Error from curl connection causing cron job to fail
I am running a cron job that uses curl to report overnight hacking attacks to Microsoft.
It has been working fine until the msrc reporting api failed and now gives a "Curl error: (7) : Couldn't connect to server" and a 404 error. This then causes the cron job to fail and repeat.
I have determined that the rest of the cron job works perfectly it's the 404 error from msrc that is causing the issue.
What I need to do is disregard or cancel the 404 error from the curl link to msrc and return a 200 code.
I have tried forcing a 200 at the start of the cron job using
header("Status: 200 OK");
to no effect.
Also I tried
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
But that didn't seem to do anything either.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
